# Proxying API request from React frontend to Flask backend on two separate Heroku apps

Tags: python, reactjs, heroku, flask, create-react-app

I am working on a web application with a create-react-app frontend and a Flask API backend with Flask-RESTful. I built the app locally and it works on my computer, but now I am unsuccessfully trying to deploy it to Heroku.

I deployed the Flask backend and the React frontend as two different Heroku dynos, so each one has their own URL. When I go to the URL for the frontend, it appears to be working fine, and the backend URL seems to work too. However, the app relies on API calls to the backend, and I am having trouble successfully sending requests to my backend.

When I was working locally, I would run the flask backend with the `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app` and the frontend with the `npm start` command. The app worked fine with relative calls in my Axios function calls as long as I put `"proxy": "https://localhost:8000"` in my `package.json` file in my frontend app. In general, I followed this tutorial: https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/.

I thought I could simply edit the `proxy` field in the `package.json` file to point to the URL of my backend Heroku app, and then I wouldn't have to change anything else. However, when I deploy using this, I find that the requests to my endpoint are being made to `https://my-frontend-app.herokuapp.com/<endpoint>` instead of `https://my-backend-app.herokuapp.com/<endpoint>`.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "heroku-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "plotly.js": "^1.39.2",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "reactstrap": "^6.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "https://star-employees-api.herokuapp.com"
}
```

My requests look like this:

```
axios.get('/analyze', data)
.then((response) => {
    // Handle request response here
};
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? This is my first time deploying an app like this and using Heroku, so I'm not sure if I'm way off base here. If there is a better way to deploy this kind of app, please let me know as well.
I can provide any other code snippets or file structure if it's helpful, just not sure what would be helpful at this point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `proxy` field is only used for the Webpack dev server in development. You must configure your production server separately.

Comment: @Tholle I see, are there any resources for how to do this? Based on my very rudimentary research, I need to use something like nginx to take the place of the webpack dev server? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have never hosted anything on heroku myself, but if you can use nginx [this might be wroth a try](https://serverfault.com/questions/857348/nginx-serving-a-create-react-app-application-on-one-port-and-my-api-on-another).

Comment: It looks like the create-react-app-buildpack for Heroku I'm using contains this kind of functionality out of the box as mentioned here: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#proxy

I followed the instructions but it is still not working for me. I'll post an issue on GitHub and post an answer if I find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. As Tholle mentioned, the proxy field in the `package.json` file is only for the dev server. If you're using create-react-app with Heroku and the [buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack), there are some other steps. When deploying, you need to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#proxy) and add a `static.json` file in your topmost directory.

Comment: How would you go about setting this up if you were running both server and client on the same dyno?